# Where to use these words exactly: "simple," "simplicity"

Tags: word-choice, differences

I just want to know how to use these words and in which context: *simple* and *simplicity*.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question. Do you want to know what these words mean? How they are pronounced? Something else? Please try to be as specific as possible. Thanks.

Comment: @Reg: let him read through my answer.

Comment: @nOnChun: I think the question could use some improving whether or not your answer is spot on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Simple* : Adjective : Easily Understood

For eg. take this sample sentence

> Ron presented a simple proof of Fermat's long-unproven theorem.

*Simplicity* : Noun : The quality or condition of being easy to understand or do

> The simplicity of Ron's proof of Fermat's theorem is formidable

Helps?

Answer (score 1):

"Simple" is an adjective, so it is used to describe or qualify a noun or  a noun phrase.

> It was a rather *simple* task

"Simplicity" is a noun itself.

> For the sake of *simplicity*.